# Maven ClassNotFoundException in project

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I'm working in the following setup:

I have a Project A that is used to analyze another maven project B. 
Project A is added to project B as a dependency and using the exec-maven-plugin I execute the main class of project A inside project B.

Now in this main class I try to load a class from project B using the class loader I got with `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();` but I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. I also tried the class loader `this.getClass().getClassLoader();` but it didn't change anything.

I checked the classpath with `mvn -X` and the target directory of the project was added and all compiled classes are actually in there too.

If I try to check the class path from within the code I just get `/opt/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

The right class loader is the one that I get with `this.getClass().getClassLoader();`. The main problem was that I tried to load a test class and `target/test-classes` was not on the class path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("class")`

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)